# Templating C++ error

Tags: c++, templates, linked-list

I was writing code that pertained to a linkedlist, and I wanted to template the whole program. Here is what I have written:

```
template<typename T>
class Node
{
public:
    T data;
    Node* next;
    Node(){};
};
class List{
public:Node<T>* head;
List() { head= NULL; } //constructor
```

For that, it works just fine with my other functions. However, I am also trying to write a function copy, which copies the list to another.

```
List Copy(List copyme){
    List<T> x; 
    x = new List<T>;
    Node<T>* current = copyme.head;
    while (current != NULL){
        x.ListInsertHead(current->data);
        current = current->next;
    }
    x.ListReverse();
    return x;
    };
```

I am receiving errors about templating the class, what should I write in this case? Thanks. The errors are just undeclared identifiers, which happen because I'm templating it wrongly.

Comment: What errors are you receiving?  Please don't just tell us "errors" and omit the details.

Comment: If it's a huge wall of errors, show us the first, complete error.  We can help you understand what it's saying.  But only if we can see it.

Comment: `List` needs to be a class template with parameter `T`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
template<typename T>
class Node
{
    public:
       T data;
       Node* next;
       Node(T val){ data = val; }
};

template <typename T>
class List
{
public:
       Node<T>* head;
       List() { head= NULL; } //constructor
};

template <typename T> 
List <T> Copy(List <T> copyme)
{
    List<T> x; 
    x = new List<T>;
    Node<T>* current = copyme.head;
    while (current != NULL){
        x.ListInsertHead(current->data);
        current = current->next;
    }
    x.ListReverse();
    return x;
}
```

Comment: I could change the input argument to `Copy` to `List<T> const& copyme`.